# Use powershell to set azure active directory user settings

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

Would like to use PowerShell to set the values for Azure Active Directory|Users|User settings.
App Registration - Yes/No
Adiministraion portal - Yes/No
LinkedIn account connections - Yes/Selected Group/No

I have looked at the azure module and the azuread module, but I was not able to find a way to get to User settings.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please check this article about asking question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. also, please edit your question and add an example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**User settings** are not supported to be configured with Powershell cmd currently.

If you have this requirement, please post your idea on [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).